# passing table and column name dynamically using bind variables

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11gr2

Is there a way to pass column and table names dynamically to a query using bind variables? This could be done by using a simple concatenation operator `||`, but I would like a different approach by which this can be achieved.

**EDIT**

```
OPEN abc_cur FOR 'Select :column_name
                  from :table_name' 
                USING column_name,table_name;
```

In this example I am passing `column_name` as `empno,ename` and `table_name` as `emp`

But this approach is not working for me. Is it possible to have a different approach other that the traditional approach of concatenation?

Comment: @Adrian: Are you getting what i meant with the question?

Comment: Honestly, no. I think you should elaborate.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Table and column names cannot be passed as bind variables, no.  The whole point of bind variables is that Oracle can generate a query plan once for the statement and then execute it many times with different bind variable values.  If the optimizer doesn't know what table is being accessed or what columns are being selected and filtered on, it can't generate a query plan.

If your concern relates to SQL injection attacks, and assuming that dynamic SQL is actually necessary (most of the time, the need to resort to dynamic SQL implies problems with the data model), you can use the [`DBMS_ASSERT` package](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/dbms_assert_10gR2.php) to validate that the table names and column names don't contain embedded SQL.

Comment: I am concerned with dynamically create a sql query and then execute it .Is there any  alternative for that ?

Comment: @ Gaurav Soni- What is your concern?

Comment: i can create my dynamic sql with concatenation of string  like `v_sql:=select '||column_name||' from dual where 1=1` and then another string like that ,how can we create this more efficiently ,i mean wats the other approach other than this

Comment: :Is there any more optimised efficient approach other than this?

Comment: @Gaurav Soni- Are you worried that string concatenation itself is slow?  That you're doing excessive hard parses?  That you're opening security holes for SQL injection attacks?  Or something else?  Most well-designed systems have no need to resort to dynamic SQL so I'm always suspicious that dynamic SQL is being used to cover up a poor design.  If you actually need the queries to be dynamic, though, you need to assemble the string dynamically.

Comment: THanks for the answer, i think you are the best explainator and tutor in this field.Appriciated

Answer (score 6):

No you cannot.  Changing the table or column names in a query changes the **semantics** of that query - i.e. it becomes a **different** query.

Bind variables are all about passing different values to the **same** query.  The optimiser can reuse the query with different values without having to re-parse it and optimise it.