# Dynamically use select into statement

Tags: plsql

what is wrong with the following function?

```
create or replace function getNameById(myId in number) return number
is
  query varchar2(500);
  myName varchar2(20);
begin


  query :='SELECT users_name INTO :myname FROM USERS_TABLE WHERE USERS_ID = :myid';

  execute 
  immediate query 
  USING out myName, myId;

  dbms_output.put_line(myName);
  return(myName);
end getNameById;
```

If instead of a query I use:

```
SELECT users_name INTO myName FROM USERS_TABLE WHERE USERS_ID = 81;
```

The execution succeeds however

The problem is when I add " INTO :myname " I get an error at execution..

is it not possible to use INTO while doing dynamic sql?

EDIT: SOLVED!

```
create or replace function getNameById(myId in number) return varchar2
is
  query varchar2(500);
  myName users_table.users_name%type;

begin

  query :='SELECT users_name FROM USERS_TABLE WHERE USERS_ID = :myid'; 
  execute immediate query INTO myName USING myId;

  dbms_output.put_line(myName);
  return(myName);

end getNameById;
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use the into in your select statement

```
create or replace function getNameById(myId in number) return number
is
    query varchar2(500);
    myName varchar2(20);
    rezult varchar(100);
begin

    query :='SELECT users_name FROM USERS_TABLE WHERE USERS_ID = '||myid;

        execute 
        immediate query 
        into rezult;

  dbms_output.put_line(rezult);
  return(rezult);
end getNameById;
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot bind table names in Oracle dynamic SQL.  You need to put the table name directly into the dynamic SQL.  Try using the following stored procedure instead:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE getNameById (
   myName IN VARCHAR2,
   myId IN NUMBER) AS
   where_clause VARCHAR2(100) := ' WHERE USERS_ID = ' || myId;
BEGIN
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT users_name INTO ' || myname || ' FROM USERS_TABLE' || where_clause;
END;
```

Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9723931/passing-table-and-column-name-dynamically-using-bind-variables) and [here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/525821?start=0&tstart=0) for more information.