# Appropriate Use of Bind Variables

Tags: oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql, bind-variables

In the following PL/SQL block, a bind variable is used in the WHERE clause:

```
declare
symbol varchar2(6) := 'EPIC';
begin
execute immediate 'delete from stock where symbol = :symbol'
using symbol;
end;
/
```

This block executes successfully, however, something like the following will fail:

```
declare
symbol varchar2(15) := 'employees';
begin 
execute immediate 'delete from :symbol where last_name = ''Kochar'''
using symbol
end;
/
```

My question is: can we use bind variables in any other context besides passing a value to a WHERE clause like in the first example?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [passing table and column name dynamically using bind variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9723931/passing-table-and-column-name-dynamically-using-bind-variables)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You can bind into your SQL statement only those expressions(literals,
>   variables, complex expressions) that replace placeholders for data
>   values inside the dynamic string. you cannot bind in the names of
>   schema elements(tables, columns, etc) or entrie chunks of the SQL
>   statement. For those parts of your string, you must use
>   concatenation(operator)

So Use as in the following :

```
SQL> create table employees(empid int,last_name varchar2(50));

Table created

SQL> insert into employees values(111,'Kochar');

1 row inserted

SQL> select * from employees;

EMPID LAST_NAME
----- ----------
  111 Kochar

SQL> 
SQL> declare
  2    symbol varchar2(15) := 'employees';
  3  begin
  4    execute immediate 'delete '||symbol||' where last_name = ''Kochar''';
  5  end;
  6  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed

SQL> select * from employees;

EMPID LAST_NAME
----- ----------
-- i.e. no row(s) returned.
```

Answer (score 2):

Bind Variables is only transmit values .

It allow to reuse the same query , but with different values .

A table name is not a value .