# UnicodeDecodeError in pyodbc when passing parameters to cursor.execute(), but not when writing parameters directly to string

Tags: python, sql, windows, oracle, pyodbc

When trying to pass a parameter to a prepared statement using pyodbc, Python returns a UnicodeDecodingError. However, when adding the parameter directly to the prepared statement string, there is no such error.

I work on Windows 10 (64bit) using the pyodbc library in Python 3 and with an "Oracle in OraDB12Home1" driver. Retrieving information from the database works fine when adding all parameters directly to the string containing the sql-statements.

Here are two examples that throw the mentioned error

**Example 1**

```py
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
sql_statement = "select col1 from ? where col1 is not null;"
params = ("db_name")
cursor.execute(sql_statement,params)
```

**Example 2**

```py
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
sql_statement = "select col1 from db_name where col1 is not ?;"
params = ("null")
cursor.execute(sql_statement,params)
```

The resulting error is in both cases as follows:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)

~\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\fasttext\lib\encodings\utf_16_le.py in decode(input, errors)

     15 def decode(input, errors='strict'):

---> 16     return codecs.utf_16_le_decode(input, errors, True)

     17

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-16-le' codec can't decode bytes in position 160-161: illegal encoding
```

Note that choosing a different database (e.g. replacing "db-name" with "different_db_name") does not do the trick and still throws the same error.

**Expected behaviour**

I expect the same result as for the following example, which runs without error:

```py
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
sql_statement = "select col1 from db_name where col1 is not null;"
cursor.execute(sql_statement)
```

Also, note that passing *different* parameters works fine. For example, the execution of the following code throws no error, even though the only difference to the examples provided above is the parameter that is passed.

```py
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
sql_statement = "select ? from db_name where col1 is not null;"
params = ("col1")
cursor.execute(sql_statement)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`X is null` and `X is not null` are clauses of SQL language - see: [NULL conditions](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/conditions008.htm#SQLRF52152). 
There are SQL keywords, `NULL` keyword in these clauses is a part of the syntax, you simply can not pass a keyword as a parameter.
Therefore this is incorrect:

```
sql_statement = "select col1 from db_name where col1 is not ?"
```

You must use something like this instead:

```
param = "null"
if param == "null":
    sql_statement = "select col1 from db_name where col1 is null"
else:
    sql_statement = "select col1 from db_name where col1 is not null"
```

---

The same applies to table names - they cannot be passed as bind variables.

I will not explain why, there are plenty of answers on this subject, for example this one:
 [passing table and column name dynamically using bind variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9723931/passing-table-and-column-name-dynamically-using-bind-variables)

Therefore this is incorrect:

```
sql_statement = "select col1 from ? where col1 is not null"
```

You must use this instead:

```
param = "db_name"
sql_statement = "select col1 from " + param + " where col1 is not null"
```