# Java SQL PreparedStatement is not working

Tags: java

I have written this code with **Statement** and it is working well:

```java
 protected ResultSet tabQuery(String query) throws SQLException {

String tabQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + query;

Statement statement = connection.createStatement();

return statement.executeQuery(tabQuery);

}
```

But when I trying to convert it with **PreparedStatement** but it is not working with SQL syntax error.

```java
protected ResultSet tabQuery(String query) throws SQLException {

String tabQuery = "SELECT * FROM ?";

PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(tabQuery);

statement.setString(1, query);

System.out.println(statement);

return statement.executeQuery();

}
```

Comment: What Error are you getting?

Comment: You cannot pass table names as bind variables. Please look at the answer for following question to understand more: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9723931/passing-table-and-column-name-dynamically-using-bind-variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use the `?` operator on tables.

You can do something like `"SELECT ? FROM mytable;"` but it does not work the other way.

I recommand using stored procedures, not using prepared statements, changing your db structure or create prepared statements for every query and cache them:

```
Map<String,PreparedStatement> cache=new HashMap<>();
```

and

```
PreparedStatement stmt;
if(cache.contains(query)){
    stmt= cache.get(query)
}else{
     stmt=new PreparedStatement("SELECT * FROM `"+query.replace("`","\\`")+"`");
    cache.put(query,stmt);
}
return stmt.executeQuery();
```

Comment: Not only should you always use prepared statements, creating your own prepared statement caching is most likely completely useless, as the drivers and servers tend to handle those a lot more efficiently themselves. Consult your database and driver documentation for prepared statement caching. Main problem in the question is really about design. You just don't create a method that returns **everything** from any table you pass as a parameter...

Answer (score 0):

Giving table names as variables for SQL queries is a bad practice.

It's better to write different queries for different tables.

- `getCustomers` for the **Customers** table
- `getAccounts` for **Accounts** table

etc.