# Column bind variables in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Snowflake offers the (unusual) ability to have bind variables in table names:
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/literals-table.html

I'm wondering if the same can be done for columns, something like this:

```sql
select count(1) from mytable where ? is null
```

Comment: if there's no documentation, I tend to try and see if it works..

Comment: I did that, it doesn't work outright. I'm wondering if there's something similar to what they do for table parameterization, because it's [not normally something you can do](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9724099/5326679)

Comment: well if you use a stored procedure you can do it, as you can write the SQL, and last I understood there is no pre-computed plan, thus no issue with allowing variable table names. Allow I don't understand the context in which your using semi-dynamic SQL, yet cannot form full SQL at that layer.. aka we orcastrate all our sql from node.js apps we run in aws, as tasks where not around, so that was all there was, so from there where can script all our dynamic sql needs.

Comment: The need isn't really important to answer the question at hand, but if you're curious I'm writing an app that does a bunch of data quality checks on some views. The models for the views are stored in yaml files that define the fields of each view and some characteristics like nullability or allowed values.

Comment: nod, so if your parsing files and running sql from code side, you can write your expanded sql there. we use a {{ mustache }} style variable replacement in our system.

Comment: Yeah I definitely agree I can concatenate the strings myself but would rather use a bind variable for the sanitization safety and correctness

Comment: I agree if your driving data from "input" sanitized all the way. But if its `SQL + YAML` your devs write verse `only SQL`  your devs write then are equally inside the trusted loop..

Comment: I have a similar problem. I suppose you did not found a solution. Did you?

Comment: @momobo nah, I just plugged in values with interpolation and a bit of homegrown sanitization logic.. for the most part I'm fine because the code that does this isn't exposed to user input.

Comment: Thanks, this bug is annoying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, the identifier literal is what you are looking for:

```
select count(1) from mytable where identifier(?) is null
```

Docs: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/identifier-literal.html