# SQLite dynamically bind column name from user input

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite

Little did I know at first. I thought I could just use an f string. After reading about insertion attacks (by reading I mean a stick-man comic strip) and about SQLite parameters with the dangling comma, I have this.

```
stat_field = input("Enter stat field: ") 
query = "SELECT player_name, (?) FROM stattable"
conn = sqlite3.connect('pitches.db')
df = pd.read_sql_query(query, conn, params=(stat_field,))
conn.close()
```

If I type 'pfx_x' at the prompt, a column in stattable, the dataframe looks like this.

```
    player_name   (?)
0   Mike Mayers  pfx_x
1   Mike Mayers  pfx_x
2   Mike Mayers  pfx_x
```

Any idea how to get the actual data for that last column?

Comment: Good idea, however, it just changes the column name from (?) to ?. I thought if that's the column name, I'll just put pfx_x in parentheses but then it's an incorrect number of bindings error.

Comment: This doesn't seem possible. Maybe look up the string in a list of columns to validate that it's a safe/valid choice, then run the appropriate query without a bound column name like this.

Comment: If I change the value in the script, it works and I get this.    
   
       player_name  pfx_x

0     Mike Mayers   0.37

1     Mike Mayers   0.30

2     Mike Mayers  -0.77` (in column form)

Comment: Yes, if you hardcode `pfx_x` into the query string, it will work of course. But binding isn't the same as f-string interpolation. It only works on variables related to values in the table, not the query itself, if I understand correctly. So binding will work if you say `WHERE player_name=?` and pass in `"Mike Mayers"` as the bound variable but you can't say `SELECT * FROM ?;` and try to bind that with `"stattable"`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9723931/passing-table-and-column-name-dynamically-using-bind-variables) even though it's not SQLite, it should still apply.

Answer (score 0):

I was slow to understand this but ggorlen pointed me in the right direction. Basically, binding variables, or placeholders, cannot be in the SELECT/FROM statements because placeholders are designed to alter a pre-existing statement. The user can, however, choose player_name because that field is always available. I had to put all the stats I might use in the original query but I could speed up the processing by adding "WHERE player_name = ?" and then changing params to params=(player_name,).